# Bugs in converting Categorical dataset to Transaction dataset in R

Tags: r

I have been working on feature engineering and I have come up with following code to converted the categorical dataset into binary transaction dataset, but I am not able get desired output, only three columns get populated with one. Rest all remain zero.

Here's my code:

```
`binarize<-function(dataset,names){ 
  drops<-NA
  colnames(dataset)<- paste("{",names,"}:",sep = "")
  dataset<-dataset[,!(names(dataset)%in%drops)]
  dataset$id = 1:nrow(dataset)
  xt<-dataset %>% mutate_each(funs(as.character))%>% gather(key,values,starts_with("{"))
  xt$values <- apply( xt[ , c("key","values") ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "" )
  xt<-xt %>% mutate(present = 1)%>% spread(values,present,fill = 0) 
  xt<-xt%>% distinct(id)
  rmCols<-c("id","key")
  xt<-xt[,-which(names(xt) %in% rmCols)]
  return(xt)
}`
```

Can someone help me debug this? names in the argument is a character vector.

Thanks,
Prerit

Comment: Can you provide your data?

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data